# Centralized Logging for many Java Apps: Syslog vs JMS vs Http vs Local file

Tags: java, logging, rest, jms, syslog

I want all my applications log to be centralized (ideally in near real-time). We will use a Log4 Appender. Which one should I use:

1. Send log event in a JMS Queue
2. Syslog / syslog-ng
3. Write to a localfile and use rsync (every 3second) to replicate the log
4. Do a POST to a centralized REST Http Service

Which one are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on your requirements.  Logging to a queue (as in JMS) gives you the most flexibility of your options as your log operation can return as soon as the log message has been written to the queue.  You are then free to have another process take those log messages off the queue and write them to your preferred logging store (database, file system, ...).

The (slight) downside is your log messages will lag slightly behind the system that is logging, but this is almost always the case, even with file-based logging.

Comment: Would you say that sending a String to a remote Syslog would be faster than a JMS+WMQ queue?

I know that syslog-ng can acknowledge the reception of the message and then perform other routing to the event (send to a file, d.b., email etc)

Comment: Simple answer is I don't know, but I could see syslog being faster if you compared it to a JMS solution that used persistent messages.  If you don't need persistent messages (possibility of losing log messages), then you can make JMS faster.  In the end, you'd need to measure the performance if speed is a requirement.

Answer (score 2):

This may be overkill but have you looked at [Splunk](http://www.splunk.com/)? For Java apps, I've used either Log4J or SLF4J to log to files, then Splunk can aggregate the logs and make them searchable.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Log4 (Log4j?), but does it have a database appender?  This would provide the centralization you need and would eliminate any need to replicate your logs.

Answer (score 0):

It really very much depends on what you want.. I don't think syslog is a good choice for application logging though, it's more suitable for infrastructure logs. Without knowing too much details, all 4 options you listed look OK. We use [this](http://www.logfaces.com).

Answer (score 0):

btw, log4j does have [AsyncAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/AsyncAppender.html) which uses queue and dedicated consumer-thread for logging from it